# What 'filterDirectory' of Camel File component does?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I wonder what is the purpose of 'filterDirectory' parameter in Camel File component. I didn't managed to find any examples with this property. According to [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html):

> Filters the directory based on Simple language. For example to filter on current date, you can use a simple date pattern such as ${date:now:yyyMMdd}.

I wrote some sample route to check it behaviour:

```
public class FilterDirectoryRoute extends RouteBuilder {

private static final String FILE = "file:";
private static final String START_DIR = "C:/test/camel/filterDirectoryRoute";

private final Map<String, String> params = Map.of(
  "noop", "true",
  "recursive", "true",
  "filterDirectory", "${date:now:yyyy/DDD}"
);

@Override
public void configure() {

from(FILE + START_DIR + fileParams(params))
    .log(DEBUG, log, "date = ${date:now:yyyy/DDD}")
    .log(DEBUG, log, "body = ${body}")
    .end();
  }
}
```

There is next structure of `filterDirectoryRoute` directory:

```
filterDirectoryRoute
 ┣ 2020
 ┃ ┣ 1.txt
 ┃ ┣ 105.txt
 ┃ ┗ 15.txt
 ┗ 2021
 ┃ ┣ 268
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 268.txt
 ┃ ┣ 269
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 269.txt
 ┃ ┣ 270
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 270.txt
 ┃ ┣ 271
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 271.txt
 ┃ ┣ 272
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 272.txt
```

With such configuration the route just traverse all files in directory and read it. So the `filterDirectory` has no effect as it doesn't enter `2021/270` (270 is the current day of the year).

If I delete `recursive` parameter no files are processed as there are no files in starting directory directly.

**So the question is**: how `filterDirectory` option can be used and what it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the `filterDirectory` query-parameter is used in conjunction with the [File Language.](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/file-language.html) That means that you would have to construct a filter that in essence produces a boolean result. Something akin to `filterDirectory="${file:name} == ${date:now:yyyy/DDD}"`.

<s>NOTE: I have not verified this myself.</s>

#### EDIT: I have now verified my hunch

The following works and only reads the file `2.txt`.

```java
@Component
public class SampleFileRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://folder?recursive=true&filterDirectory=${file:name} == 2021")
                .log("${header.CamelFileRelativePath}");
    }
}
```

```
folder
 ┣ 2020
 ┃ ┣ 1.txt
 ┗ 2021
 ┃ ┣ 2.txt
```

Comment: AFAIK `filterFile` option is used to filter files in starting folder

Comment: Camel File component considers directories to be files as well, so the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/file-component.html#_query_parameters_93_parameters) saying "Simple-language", to me at-least, points to it being the same format as `filterFile`.